# Provide bigquery.jobUser role to ServiceAccount using Java SDK, "not supported"?

Tags: java, google-api, google-bigquery, google-api-java-client

I'm using the Google Java SDK to create and manage service accounts. In general, it works great. However, I'm trying to add the 'bigquery.jobUser' role to a newly created ServiceAccount, but the API keeps telling me that the role is not valid for my resource.

There's not a ton of documentation for the Java SDK that I can find in this area, so I'm clearly doing something wrong, perhaps in specifying my resource.

Hoping someone can eyeball this and see if anything jumps out? I've been at this for days and I feel like I"m sooooo close....

```
           // assume successful service account creation:
            serviceAccount = create.execute();


            // now set the IAM policy for bigquery.user for this service account.
            String[] serviceAccountsArray = new String[] {"serviceAccount:" + serviceAccount.getEmail()};
            String targetRole = "roles/bigquery.jobUser";

            LinkedList<Binding> bindings = new LinkedList<>();
            Binding targetBinding = new Binding();
            targetBinding.setRole(targetRole);
            bindings.add(targetBinding);
            targetBinding.setMembers(Arrays.asList(serviceAccountsArray));

            Policy policy = new Policy();
            policy.setBindings(bindings);

            SetIamPolicyRequest setIamPolicyRequest = new SetIamPolicyRequest();
            setIamPolicyRequest.setPolicy(policy);

            Iam.Projects.ServiceAccounts.SetIamPolicy setIamPolicy = iam.
                    projects()
                    .serviceAccounts()
                    .setIamPolicy("projects/" + bigQueryProjectId + "/serviceAccounts/" + serviceAccount.getEmail(), setIamPolicyRequest);

            Policy newPolicy = setIamPolicy.execute();
```

Unfortunately, I always get the following exception:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 

400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Role roles/bigquery.jobUser is not supported for this resource.",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Role roles/bigquery.jobUser is not supported for this resource.",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

Comment: Does it work for any of the other predefined roles? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery.user

Comment: Thanks for reading...Unfortunately not, I've tried every roles/bigquery.* role defined in that documentation. I feel like I must be fundamentally misunderstanding the proper way to use the Java SDK to add a role to a Service Account, but darned if I can find any documentation or code samples of this operation.

Answer (score 0):

The `bigquery.*` roles do not seem to be applicable to service accounts according to the list of roles here https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles and here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control though it is possible to create service accounts through the cloud console with the required permissions (which suggests it is possible somehow).

You can apply more general roles such as Viewer, Editior or Owner (mentioned here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#transitioning_from_primitive) using the api.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, in hindsight the error message returned was obviously telling me as such, but it seemed reasonable (to a relative google cloud newbie) that this was the right SDK call to add an IAM policy binding to a service account.

I did find a way with SDK to update the ENTIRE map of the IAM policies using a pull/update/push approach (respecting the etag). However, during one test I mistakenly sent an empty payload:

```
[]
```

To the IAM endpoint, and completely blew away every ACL in my entire project, even the owner privileges! Fortunately only a Dev environment this time, but a full POST of the entire payload every time seemed risky to me.

Ultimately, I ended up finding a gcloud command line option (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/add-iam-policy-binding), which just appends the policy binding like I wanted, like:

> gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding

And wrapped this call in a ProcessBuilder.start() in my Java code (pseudo code)

```
        List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();
        commands.add(gcloudCommandLineLocation);
        commands.add("projects");
        commands.add("add-iam-policy-binding");
        commands.add(bigQueryProjectId);
        commands.add("--member");
        commands.add("serviceAccount:" + serviceAccount.getEmail());
        commands.add("--role");
        commands.add("roles/bigquery.jobUser");

        // build the process
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);

        // cross the streams!
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

        // start the process
        Process process = pb.start();
```

Not the perfect solution, but reaches my goal of appending a BigQuery ACL to a newly created service account in Java, so I'm happy to move on. Ultimately I'd like to discover the proper way to do this in the SDK, but for now I feel like I found an answer that satisfies our project.